# Cleaning up MATLAB code

Tags: matlab

I'm spending quite abit of time cleaning up old MATLAB code - This function attempts to disable Java and uicomponent handles which are properties of some object - any thoughts on how to write this function 'better'? Thanks

```
function disable(obj)
    all_props = properties(obj);
    for ii = 1:size(all_props, 1)
        try
            set(obj.(all_props{ii}), 'Enabled', 0)
        end
        try
            set(obj.(all_props{ii}), 'Enable', 'Off')
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: That function seems to be quite straightforward actually. Though ofcourse there are som variable-names that I would not use myself in MATLAB. Use _k_ or _kk_ for counters in loops. Ofcourse _ii_ is not a technical problem but it is a close cousin to _i_, which is the built-in symbol for the imaginery unit (never use _i_).

Answer (score 2):

This all looks pretty OK, I'd personally rename the iterator variable 'ii' to something more literal (i.e. iProperty) and at the beginning of the loop, I'd put something like

```
property = obj.(all_props{iProperty});
```

to avoid the repeated code afterwards (if your objects allow this).

Instead of 'size(all_props,1)' you could also use 'numel(all_props)'. In this case (with a 1-dimensional array) the outcome is the same and it looks cleaner if you ask me.

If you'd like your code more condense and with less repetition: you can always store 'Enable' and 'Enabled' together with 0 and 'Off' in some array/struct and iterate over these values. It has both its advantages (easily extended to other field names (e.g. 'Disabled' = 1), less code duplication (try-end)) but also disadvantages (extra for loop, extra variables, ...).